# Troubleshoot to design a button with icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to design a button. I have this anchor:

```
 <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> sites</a></li>
```

Here how it looks:

[image]

I need to change the look above to make sites word down the tree. Here is the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place a `<br>` tag between icon and text. And let the `<a>` tag center it`s content. Something like this should work:

```
<li><a href="#" style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i> <br> sites</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

While inserting a `<br>` is an easy fix, it's not the best one.

I would suggest you add a new class within your a tag, and then set the icon inside it to display as a block. You can then set the entire link to appear as center aligned text.

I would also replace the `<i>` tags with `<span>` as it best describes the element as either block or inline.

```
<a href="#" class="yourClass">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></span>sites
</a>

.yourClass {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.yourClass .glyphicon {
    display:block;
}
```